# How to use jQuery on a link and make it display the link in a text field on click?

Tags: jquery

What I'm trying to achieve is simple. I just don't know the jQuery lingo' to make it happen. I want to be able to click on a link, and the link output exactly what "the link" is into a text field. I imagine it'd go something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('a.text-display').click(function(){
    "copy that link text and display it in a textbox"
   });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost there:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('a.text-display').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); //don't follow the link
        var linkText = $(this).text();
        $('#mytextfield').val(function(index, oldValue) {return oldValue + ' ' + linkText } ); //add the text to the current value of the textfield (input text)
    });
});
```

Comment: Sweet! bout to test this baby out.

Comment: Is that preventDefault() similar to the javascript: void(0) ?

Comment: No, it prevents the default event set by the browser (As to follow a link if clicked)

Comment: Ok, the script above did the initial job- but how do I keep making it so that the links don't clear out the field each time a link is clicked? for example: if i made the links A, B, C, D, E how could i click each one of those and make it display in the textbox "A B C D E"?

Comment: See my updated answer. You can pass into val() a function, of which the second param is the current value. http://api.jquery.com/val/

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like this?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('a.text-display').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); //don't follow the link
        $(this).replaceWith('<input value="'+ $(this).attr("href") +'">');
    });
});​
```

See it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/EJcRB/

Comment: No, but that is a cool trick. I need the links to all be in the same spot and it will simply display in a text form